# Question about writing cyclometric function in function of $x$

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I have an excercise about cyclometric functions and I'm stuck right now:
$\cot(2\operatorname{arcsec}x)$

Let $ y=\operatorname{arcsec}x \Leftrightarrow \sec y=x$ then $$\cot 2y=\frac  {\cos2y}{\sin2y}=\frac {\cos^2y-\sin^2y}{2\sin y\cos y}$$

Now whatever I do, I don't seem to find a solution.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Principal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values) value of  $\arccos,$

$\displaystyle \cos y=\frac1x\implies0\le y\le\pi\implies\sin y\ge0$ and 
$\displaystyle\sin y=+\sqrt{1-\cos^2y}$