# Show that $\sin^{-1}x=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Show that $\sin^{-1}x=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)$ for $|x|<1$

Question: what is wrong with the following reasoning?

Define: $x=\sin(y)$

$x^2=\sin^2(y)$

$1-x^2=\cos^2(y)$

$\frac{1}{1-x^2}=\sec^2(x)=1+\tan^2(y)$

$\tan^2(y)=\frac{1}{1-x^2}-1=\frac{x^2}{1-x^2}$

$\tan(y)=\pm\frac{|x|}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

$\sin^{-1}x=\tan^{-1}\left(\pm\frac{|x|}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)$

So I end up with $\pm$ and the absolute-value-sign, which are not part of the original equation. How to get rid of them?

By the way, I know that there are other ways to show this statement is true. But the question is what is wrong with this method.

Comment: $x^2=\sin^2 y$ would be true even if $x=-\sin y$. This gives an extraneous solution.

Comment: @GoodDeeds Ok, so that explains the $\pm$. How about the absolute value?

Comment: @GoodDeeds Can I then simply remove the negative value?

Answer (score 4):

For example:

$$\begin{align*}&\left(\arcsin x\right)'=\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\\{}\\&\left(\arctan\frac x{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)'=\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}+\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}}{1-x^2}\cdot\frac1{1-\frac{x^2}{1-x^2}}=\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\end{align*}$$

and we know that if on some open interval $\;I\;$ we have $\;f'=g'\;$ then $\;f(x)=g(x)+K\;,\;\;K\;$ a constant, for all $\;x\in I\;$ , for for $\;x\in (-1,1)\;$

$$\arcsin x=\arctan\frac x{\sqrt{1-x^2}}+K$$

Now just choose $\;x=0\;$ to check $\;K=0\;$ and thus the equality

Answer (score 4):

Like  [Question about writing cyclometric function in function of x](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/886187/question-about-writing-cyclometric-function-in-function-of-x/886188#886188),

if $\sin^{-1}x=u,-\dfrac\pi2\le u\le\dfrac\pi2\implies\cos u\ge0$

and $\sin u= x,\cos u=+\sqrt{1-x^2}\implies\tan u=?$

$\implies u=\arctan(?)$